# What is a small tent kind of shop on the side of the road called?

Tags: terminology, names, north-american-english

What is a small tent kind of shop on the side of the road called?

It can sell stuff like newspapers, snacks, coffee, and other small things. The only two things that come to mind are "a hot dog stand" and "street vendor" (though the latter is the person). So, I was wondering what other words for it may be?

In my language it's called a kiosk or simply a van, whether it's immovable or on the wheels, but from what I've googled, the pictures say it's not the same thing in English.

Here is what I want to know the name for:

[image: roadside shop]

Comment: You deleted a number of photos  but left the last one. Were those _not_ what you were looking for? Because your accepted answer is closer to the pictures you deleted, and not good for the picture you kept.

Comment: Accepted answer shows a *cart*. That's a *concession trailer*.

Comment: @Mitch yes, the picture that is in your answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In that case I suggest that you un-delete one of the other photos and remove the current one. The photo you have in your question now is a trailer and probably not designed to be pushed/pulled by hand.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### pushcart

A type of cart with wheels that you manually push.

[*Dictionary.com*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pushcart) says the term is primarily used in the US and in Canada

> mainly US and Canadian a handcart, typically having two wheels and a canvas roof, used esp by street vendors.  Also called: *barrow*

*[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_cart)* suggests that it is typically known as a **food cart**

> **A food cart** is a mobile kitchen set up on the street to prepare and sell street food to passers-by. Food carts are often found in cities worldwide selling food of every kind.
>
> Food carts come in two basic styles.
>
> - One allows the vendor to sit or stand inside and serve food through a window.
> - In the other, the vendor stands next to the cart, while all the room in the cart is used for storage and to house the cooking machinery, usually a grilling surface.
> - Some food carts are towed by another vehicle, **while some are pushed by a human or animal.**

It can also be simply called a [**food stall with wheels**](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1309&bih=603&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=RsdOXICHJ9C2kwWO3oOABQ&q=food%20stalls%20%22with%20wheels%22&oq=food%20stalls%20%22with%20wheels%22&gs_l=img.3...36598.38764..39084...0.0..0.119.228.0j2......1....1..gws-wiz-img.ksOJbCyKsBw), or a [**vendor cart**](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&q=vendor%20cart&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8jKHtkZDgAhUKsqQKHV-YBH4QsAR6BAgEEAE&biw=1309&bih=603)

[image]
*A hot dog cart*

If the food cart is part of a vehicle, it is called a **[foodtruck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_truck)**

Comment: foodcart, right! I also remembered a simple "burger van".

Comment: @dee the thing in your picture is not at all called a pushcart in US/Canada. The thing in Mari-Lou's picture can be called a pushcart in US/Can, but would more likely be called a hotdog stand.

Comment: @Mitch I posted this answer *before* the OP deleted all the images. The question was also more generic.

Comment: They still have one image at the bottom of the OP, which is what I was referring to and which looks like a 'food truck' in US. It's unclear if the OP wants a generic for the function or a specific word for the conveyance (or any and all).

Comment: Well @Mitch I suggest you look at the other four images that were also posted, and take note that Pam's answer also suggested "barrow", and I would never call the stand in this post a barrow nor the one that has been edited in the OP, and I don't think she would have either.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The OP deleted them so that is a strong hint that they are _not_ the things they want a word for. But I've asked the OP for clarification.

Comment: Yes, pushcart and pushcart vendors (for example, in NYC); larger ones with a van are called food trucks.

Comment: Never heard this (US).

Comment: @AzorAhai what would you call it I wonder? I'm American myself and I didn't know what to call it but push cart seems to fit.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I'm not sure I have a name for it (it's not super my common in my city).

Comment: While the things being used are pushcarts, a pushcart is not just something used to sell food or other stuff from.  You might use a pushcart for almost anything where you needed to haul a bunch stuff around for any purpose.  I don't think there is an English word for just the sort of pushcart used to sell stuff from.

Answer (score 13):

The phrase [market cart](https://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/market-cart) brings up some similar images in eBay. I think I’ve also seen this kind of stand called a "barrow", too. [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Barrow) list the following for "barrow":

> chiefly Brit a handcart, typically having two wheels and a canvas roof, used esp by street vendors

Which neatly describes your images in a British fashion and gives "handcart" as an alternative.

Comment: The OP is asking for North American English, not British. 'market cart' would not be used in NA.

Comment: @Mitch [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=market+cart&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmarket%20cart%3B%2Cc0) suggests it's uncommon in NA but it has been used in the past. However eBay.com only has a couple of relevant images (and they're both from the UK).

Comment: I suspect that *market cart* in North America never changed from the original British meaning of *market cart*: a cart used for transporting goods to the market, as well as for selling them out of. [See the English artist's Thomas Gainsborough's 1786 painting](https://www.wikiart.org/en/thomas-gainsborough/the-market-cart-1786).

Answer (score 7):

I guess you could call it [**a vending cart**](https://www.pps.org/article/vending) or **a street vending cart** (you could even call it **a mobile vending kiosk** if you wanted). That is, it's a cart that's used for vending or selling things. If you go and do a quick search on Google, you will see that you're going to get a lot of hits with these phrases. So, these terms are very simple and actually used in the real world.

Answer (score 6):

A **Market Stall** (or simply a **stall**) might be what you're looking for. This would be used to describe a tent-like structure, not something on wheels. Though the word Kiosk is also used (certainly in British English).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_stall

Comment: To me, as a Brit, a **kiosk** is usually a small but reasonably permanent structure. Certainly not a tent or anything on wheels.

Comment: I'd probably agree! But it is useful to note that the word exists.

Comment: Australia is similar to Britain here as often the case.  The general term is a stall or market stall, and we would not use the word "cart".  Note that the image in the original question may be described as a "food truck" - this is a food stall in a van or caravan style trailer where the servers stand inside and serve you through a window.

Comment: In the UK "market stalls" are not isolated and moveable. They may be temporary but the "market" is held in a fixed location at regular intervals (e.g. the same day each week) and consists of several stalls, like this one: https://www.visitpeakdistrict.com/explore/towns-and-villages/ashbourne-p689841

Answer (score 4):

In the UK this might be known as a 'stand' or a 'van'.

A 'stand' as in a hotdog stand, although this would be applicable if the server was stood at ground level and the unit could be moved by hand.

A 'van' as in an ice-cream van, although this would not be an official definition found in the dictionary it is in common use.

Answer (score 1):

It can be called
a ***BOOTH***.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/booth:

: a stall or stand (as at a fair) for the sale or exhibition of goods.

Comment: shopping cart is a thing you put your stuff in in a shop. and I'm wondering what the thing in the pictures is called. this is not shopping cart, but nonetheless, thank you for your time.

Comment: It may be OK for retailers.

Comment: A booth doesn't usually have wheels.

Answer (score 1):

I've tended to describe this sort of thing to others (and them describe it to me) as a ***kiosk***. I've always been able to understand what they meant in any given case, and vice versa.

Comment: Google image search for 'kiosk' (google.com, not google.uk) and... you won't find anything that looks like any of the pictures, deleted or not, that the OP gave.